# Different name for contact page

Tags: web, call-to-action

I'm about to launch a service online and there is something that bothers me a little bit. I have a survey in my contact page that I would want my visitors to take if they feel interested. However, people rarely open the contact page, so most of them will never see the survey. Unfortunately, the survey doesn't fit in the rest of the pages. It may in the home page, but it feels odd there. Not enough appealable such a location to me right now. So I was thinking about to maybe rename the contact page in a call-to-action way? And what would make for a good label in that case? Or perhaps is there another way to let visitors know about the survey? But I don't really like the idea of popping messages up all around, that could be more annoying than helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've gone through same situation before. I remember it was long tiring debate. I red other's answers here. It is neither interface issue mentioned by @Bharat and word selection by @Jamezrp. You just have to be little clever.

> There are mainly two modes of users: rush & wandering.

If you show any dialog box/popup especially containing forms, High chances is that user in rush will skip that.

In case of wanderer, they are more likely to fill out survey forms.

As a my conclusion, it is better to show survey forms in popups after certain interval of time so we can be sure about their mode.

Comment: Good analysis. I think showing popup in 2 minutes after page load should be fine. Obviously the time depends on what kind of website it is.

Comment: Smart approach to this problem. Thumps up for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest having a small floating button on the side of the home page with the text "take a survey" like in the following link https://renegadeworks.com/wordpress-plugin-feedback-tab-review-us-button/ will be appropriate if you realy want the user to observe it the moment they enter your website.

And in the survey part having the UI minimal helps the user to have a pleasant experience. In the following example https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/04/01/minimal-form-interface/ the minimal styling and the progress is presented in a very effective manner.

Combining these two help make a better user experience.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with including surveys on any webpage as part of the UX. Some users will find it annoying (there's always a percentage that do), but if you make it simple enough to remove and never show again for those users, then those who are interested in filling it out will do so gladly.

There's important reasoning behind this. Firstly, good UX requires user feedback, and the users who understand this are the ones you want feedback from (at least more than those who don't). There are also other things you can do, such as offer a prize (aka discount for the service, gift cards, lottery, etc.) to incentivize users to fill out the survey. None of that is wrong to do as per the UX, so long as it matches your product, site, and/or mood of the product as a whole. If it has a wildly different font and tone behind it, that will throw users off, potentially to the point of thinking that you've been hacked and that the link will lead somewhere bad.

As for the original question, there are a few options for a different name than simply "Contact":

- Contact Us
- Feedback
- Literally anything that describes "Talk to us for a reason"